# Is there a more elegant way to prove that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{n^3+2n^2+1}{n^4-10n-7}}$ diverges?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

> Is there a more elegant way to prove that
>   $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{n^3+2n^2+1}{n^4-10n-7}}$ diverges?

Here's my (to my mind) messy proof using the comparison test:$$\frac{n^3+2n^2+1}{n^4-10n-7}\geq \frac{n^3}{n^4-10n-7}=\frac{1}{n-\frac{10}{n^2}-\frac{7}{n^3}}\geq \frac{1}{n} \Longleftrightarrow n\geq n-\frac{10}{n^2}-\frac{7}{n^3} \geq 0$$
since the harmonic series diverges, the aforementioned series diverges. Is there a more elegant way? Maybe a neater diverging series to compare it to? I can't use any tests beside the quotient, root and comparsion test.

Especially these rational polynomials really bother me!

Comment: The argument is $\mathcal O(n^3/n^4)=\mathcal O(1/n)$, so it's harmonic and diverges. Easy peasy.

Comment: There's something called the limit comparison test which makes this problem trivial.

Comment: Most of the answers which have thus far been posted make use of the fact as $n$ goes to infinity, the limit of a rational function $r(n)$ is dominated by the leading terms of the numerator and denominator.  However, this kind of exercise is often given to students before they have proved such a result.  *Is* this an exercise for a class?  If so, what class?  Frankly, the answer you give is *exactly* what I would expect from a student in their first analysis class.

Comment: Thank you Xander! I actually don't know about the methods used in the answers.

Comment: @ParabolicAlcoholic, they all basically rely on the limit comparison test, which you can google.

Answer (score 4):

The general term of this series is ultimately positive, so one may use *equivalents*:

A polynomial is asymptotically equivalent to its leading term, so the general term  of your series is equivalent to
$$\frac{n^3+2n^2+1}{n^4-10n-7}\sim_\infty\frac{n^3}{n^4}=\frac1n,$$
which diverges.

Comment: $(+1)$ for speaking  about Polynomials.

Answer (score 3):

The quickest :

Near infinity,

$$u_n=\frac{n^3+2n^2+1}{n^4-10n-7} \sim \frac{n^3}{n^4}\sim \frac 1n$$

but 
$$\frac 1n >0$$ and
$$\sum_{n>0} \frac 1n \text{ diverges}$$
thus, the initial series $ \sum u_n $ diverges by limit comparison test for constant sign general term series.

Comment: +1 for insisting on the constant sign of the general term.

Answer (score 1):

For $n>17$, $0<n^4-10n-7<n^4$ and $n^3+2n^2+1>n^3,$ so $$\frac{n^3+2n^2+1}{n^4-10n-7}>\frac{n^3}{n^4}=\frac{1}{n}$$ for $n>17.$

Answer (score 1):

Ignore the terms where the denominator is negative. $n(n^{3}+2n^{2}+1) >n^{4}-10n-7$ so the given series dominates $\sum_{n\geq 3} \frac 1 n$ after ignoring $n=1$ and $n=2$.

Answer (score 1):

As said previously by Cheerful Parsnip, there is a test you can apply to this problem: limit comparison test.
Applying it:
Let's compare the original series with $\frac{1}{n}$:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\left(\frac{n^3+2n^2+1}{n^4-10n-7}\right)}{\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n^4+2n^3+n}{n^4-10n-7}\\$$
Then,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1+\frac{2}{n}+\frac{1}{n^3}}{1-\frac{10}{n^3}-\frac{7}{n^4}} = 1 > 0\\$$
Hence, as the limit tends to 1 when compared to the divergent harmonic series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}$, the original series 
$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^3+2n^2+1}{n^4-10n-7}$ also diverges.

If you want more information about it, you can search online or in Simmons George's book *Calculus with Analytic Geometry* (IIRC).
Be well, my friend!